# Python - Palindrome function: Receiving error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python, function, ipython, palindrome, words

I've been trying to use the following code to create a palindrome. I have a txt file named 'lowercasewords' which is essentially a list full of words in lowercase where I am querying from and I want to append words that are spelled the same reversed into a list named 'lines2'.

The code is below:

```
def palindrome():
    lines = open('lowercasewords.txt','r').read().splitlines()
    lines2 = []
    for x in lines:
        if (lines[x]) == (lines[x][::-1]) is True:
            lines2.append(str(x))
        else:
            pass
    print(lines2)
```

However, I receive the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Can anyone help??? I can show that the word 'level' is the same reversed:

```
str(lines[106102]) == str(lines[106102][::-1])
True
```

Comment: Hint: `str(lines[106102]) == str(lines[106102][::-1])` is only evidence that your function should work, if `x` ever has the value `106102`. Try printing x to confirm that it has a numerical value like you expect.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to read the whole file into a string, split that string into a list, and then iterate over that list. You can iterate directly over the lines in a text file. But you will need to remove the newline at the end of each line.

Comment: Also: in `lines2.append(str(x))`, `str()` is useless (it's already a string), and `(a == b)` already yields a boolean so comparing it with `True` is also totally useless (`if a == b:` works just fine). Oh, and the `else: pass` is useless too.

Comment: I'm agree with @PM2Ring. Here is more optimized for memory aproach using generators:

`def find_palindromes(fname):
    for line in open(fname):
        if line == line[::-1]:
         yield line

palindromes = find_palindromes('lowercasewords.txt')
print(list(palindromes))`

Comment: @orion_tvv It's not a good idea posting multi-line Python code in comments because the indentation gets lost.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just learning so formatting.
[it's too hard=(](https://pastebin.com/faXMhBYU)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `for x in lines:` then `x` is set to the current word in the list. Your code is then trying to get the index of that word in `lines`. This is the equivalent of saying `lines["hello"]`, which doesn't make any sense. The loop is already setting `x` to the value you want so you do not need to refer to `lines` any more.

You also do not need to check if something `is True`, the if statement is already testing for a statement being `True` or `false`.

You can fix it by simply replacing

```
if (lines[x]) == (lines[x][::-1]) is True:
```

with

```
if x == x[::-1]:
```

Comment: Was about to say this!

Comment: Thanks, @JacobTomlinson!

Comment: Oh my god I've been trying to do this for over an hour... can't believe I missed this one hahaha. Thanks so much!! :D

Comment: You're welcome. You should mark @Alexey 's answer at the correct one.